# How to force Jenkins' Maven to update Maven dependencies after they had been cached with errors

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm having a problem where I tried to run a Maven job on Jenkins, but during the execution, the firewall was blocking access to the mvn repositories; this caused an error when Maven was updating the dependencies, and it cached those errors.

Now, even after the firewall issue was resolved, the job keeps displaying this error:

> [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.2.RELEASE from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.2.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: unknown error and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10

I do know that if I was using the command line, it would be possible to use `mvn clean install -U` to force the update, but how would I do that on Jenkins?

Comment: You can add -U in jenkins job if you have the permission. If not ask an administrator

Comment: I see... adding `-U` to the goals/options field did the trick. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may concern: You can "replay" a job then modify it adding a -U option inside the maven command.

Answer (score 0):

As per Jens' suggestion, adding `-U` to the to the goals/options field solves the issue.